# Simple C++ allocator for POD types

Tags: c++, c++17

**Edit 1** after first review: I changed to use `malloc` / `free` since apparently it's also easier to optimize than `new[]` / `delete[]` : https://godbolt.org/g/CZy28o ; of course this adds an additional requirement on the alignment.

```
template <class T>
struct pod_allocator
{
    static_assert(std::is_pod_v<T>, "can only be used with POD types");
    static_assert(alignof(T) <= alignof(std::max_align_t), "type must not have specific alignment requirements");
    using value_type = T;
    auto allocate(std::size_t num)  { return (T*) malloc(sizeof(T) * num); }
    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t)   { free(p); }
};
```

---

The incentive here is to allow some compilers (clang as of clang-6.0 for instance) to remove allocations in some cases, by observing that they are able to optimize out `new`/`delete` pairs but not `::operator new`/`::operator delete` pairs : see the following in https://godbolt.org/g/jumtCU

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cinttypes>
int foo(int* src)
{
   constexpr int n = 10;    
   auto x = new int[n];
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       if(i%2 == 0)
         x[i] = src[n - i - 1] * 2;
       else
         x[i] = src[i] * src[i];
   }
   int z = 0;
   if(x[1] < 1) z = 10; 
   else z = x[2] + x[4] - x[1] - x[3];

   delete[] x;

   return z;
}
```

While the vector version... well... produces "suboptimal" assembly: https://godbolt.org/g/cZvSRb .

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <vector>
int foo(int* src)
{
   constexpr int n = 10;    
   std::vector<int> x(n);
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       if(i%2 == 0)
         x[i] = src[n - i - 1] * 2;
       else
         x[i] = src[i] * src[i];
   }
   int z = 0;
   if(x[1] < 1) z = 10; 
   else z = x[2] + x[4] - x[1] - x[3];

   return z;
}
```

Hence, here is the code of the allocator, which allows us to claim back much better codegen (https://godbolt.org/g/hvPY14) :

```
template <class T>
class pod_allocator
{
  public:
    static_assert(std::is_pod_v<T>, "can only be used with POD types");
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using is_always_equal = std::true_type;

    constexpr T* address(T& value) const noexcept { return &value; }
    constexpr const T* address(const T& value) const noexcept { return &value; }

    constexpr auto max_size() const noexcept {
        return std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T);
    }

    auto allocate(std::size_t num) { return new T[num]; }
    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t) { delete[] p; }

    constexpr void construct(T*, const T&) noexcept { }
    constexpr void destroy(T*) noexcept { }
};

template<class T1, class T2>
constexpr bool operator==(const pod_allocator<T1>&, const pod_allocator<T2>&) noexcept { return true; }

template<class T1, class T2>
constexpr bool operator!=(const pod_allocator<T1>&, const pod_allocator<T2>&) noexcept { return false; }

template<typename T>
using pod_vector = std::vector<T, pod_allocator<T>>;
```

Are there some subtle bugs that I could be introducing this way ? (not counting of course the lack of value-initialization, which is, in this case, a feature and not a bug).

Comment: I'm no expert but what about [this approach](https://godbolt.org/g/QGoGJw)?

Comment: `deallocate` leaks memory because you're using `delete` and not `delete[]`.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. That being said, @monkey0506's comment should have been a review answer. As no answer is invalidated, it's fine, but please keep this in mind for future edits.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to roll your own allocator in C++17, you can save yourself a lot of grief by just leaving everything to default. The only things you need to include are `value_type`, `allocate()`, `deallocate()`, and operators `==` and `!=`.

In fact, I believe by *not* using the defaults, you've introduced a nasty little bug. Try doing this: `auto v = pod_vector<int>(5, 42);`. This should create a vector with five `int`s, all set to `42`. But without `construct()` properly defined, who knows what will happen?

My advice:

- Your allocator should be 4 lines.

  1. the `static_assert`
  2. `value_type`
  3. `allocate()`
  4. `deallocate()`

(And you need the `==` and `!=` comparisons too.)

At the very least, either remove `construct()` or give it a sensible implementation (i.e., placement `new`). With `destroy()` it's less of an issue because you're only dealing with PODs.

---

**AFTER EDIT 1:** I'd wager the reason you're seeing better code generation for `malloc()` than `new` is that `new` throws `std::bad_alloc` automatically when it can't allocate.

I suspect if you changed your `allocate()` function to:

```
auto allocate(std::size_t num)  {
    auto const p = (T*) malloc(sizeof(T) * num);
    if (!p)
        throw std::bad_alloc{};
    return p;
}
```

you'd see a very different code gen situation.

As it stands, if you get an allocation failure, you're just returning a null pointer... which will lead to undefined behaviour, because `allocate()` *must* return a pointer to allocated memory.

Comment: I changed by taking in account your comments. Thanks ! all the tutorials for allocators I could find had all the members ; it's much clearer like this.

Comment: Hmmm.. regarding your original comment: in practice, both libc++ and MSVC's vector required me to implement == and != (both for msvc and only != for libc++).

Comment: I just checked the standard, and you are correct: the bare minimum is `value_type`, `allocate()`, `deallocate()`, `==`, and `!=`. I'll fix up my answer. (Note also I made a typo in the list! You need `deallocate()`, not `destroy()`!)